# Clear Python Input Backlog Windows

Tags: python

I have some python code that prints some text with a small delay over 30 seconds.

```
for i in range(10):
    print("test")
    sleep.sleep(0.5)
```

I then run some code to get user input:

```
answer = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N: ")
```

The problem is that if the user types and entered text while the first code is still printing this input is qued than processed by the input code. Is it possible to clear all input (including stuff entered) just before the input?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code within your source code (before the input)

```
import os
os.system('cls')  # on windows
os.system('clear') # on linux
```

Code would be

```
os.system('cls')  # on windows
answer = input("Would you like to continue? Y/N: ")
```

Using a hack(for non-Commandline runs if using third modules such as pyinstaller etc)

```
clear = "\n" * 100
print(clear)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try

Comment: Are you using console to run the program? or you are using IDE?

Comment: pyinstaller exe